# Unity Engine UI Toolkit VisualElement clone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need data list need
how to clone Visual element and `CloneTree()` how to use is not working
new **VisualElement** is not working

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < data.result.Length; i++)
{
    // Clone the listMethod VisualElement
    //var clonedListMethod = listContainer;c
    //clonedListMethod = new VisualElement(listContainer);
    //var clonedListMethod = listContainer.CloneTree();
    //VisualElement clonedListMethod = new VisualElement();
    var clonedListMethod = listContainer;

    // Set the listNumber auto-increment value
    var numberLabel = clonedListMethod.Q<Label>("listNumber");
    numberLabel.text = (i + 1).ToString();

    // Set the listUsername
    var usernameLabel = clonedListMethod.Q<Label>("listUsername");
    usernameLabel.text = data.result[i].nickName;

    // Set the listLabel
    var scoreLabel = clonedListMethod.Q<Label>("listlabel");
    scoreLabel.text = data.result[i].score.ToString();

    // Add the cloned element to the listContainer
    content.Add(clonedListMethod);
}
```

This is only one **VisualElement** copy listContainer I need many **VisualElement** render ui

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are trying to say in the start of your question, before your code. If you are having problem writting try some translator.